# Is there a practical difference between generate bcrypt salt and hash on separate function calls or auto-gen a salt and hash?

Tags: javascript, hash, bcrypt, salt, password-encryption

I honestly tried my best to find the answer here or anywhere else.
Bcrypt documentation states that there are 2 techniques to hash/salt a password:
Technique 1 (generate a salt and hash on separate function calls):

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
    });
});
```

And technique 2 (auto-gen a salt and hash):

```
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
});
```

Note that both techniques achieve the same end-result...

If they do, why do we need to add extra lines of code?
Is it just esthetical preference? Or is there any practical reason?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common implementation in a lot of libraries where they want to use the more tedious version.

- they insist that you have to pass in everything required to run the function
- and they abstract the details of passing in salt and cost and versioning away in a **salt** string

I believe the method signature should be:

```
bcrypt.HashPassword("hunter2"); //using a default cost

bcrypt.HashPassword("hunter2", 15); //if we want to force a cost
```

But nearly every other bcrypt library does something like:

```
String salt = bcrypt.GenerateSalt(); //using a default cost
bcrypt.HashPassword("hunter2", salt);

String salt = bcrypt.GenerateSalt(15); //if we want to for a cost
bcrypt.HashPassword("hunter2", salt);
```

Because then what happens internally when they go to *verify* a hash, they extract the saved salt string from the stored hash:

```
String salt = GetSaltStringFromSavedHash(savedHash);
bcrypt.HashPassword("hunter2", salt);
```

And so they just **love** this symmetry of using **`HashPassword`** in the same way for both calls.

I disagree that any of this **salt** should be exposed to the user - even if it designed to be an opaque blob (i.e. `$2b$15$aXN0aWxsbG92ZXlvdWtn...`).

I think it should be:

```
HashPassword(password);
HashPassword(password, costFactor);
```

But that's just me; and i'm the only one.